Uniswap use SDK to get historical rates (and current rate)
I am trying to use the Uniswap SDK to get historical rates between two coins on a pool. I believe the rate is simply just xy = k, where k is a constant. If someone buys n coins of x, the cost in terms of y coins would be whatever m value that makes the equation (x - n)(y + m) = k still hold.
I've been looking all over the Uniswap's SDK page and can't really find where I can find the historical data regarding this xy = k curve. I think it should be possible, but I'm not exactly sure where to find it.
I'm also looking for how the current swap rate (that is what the current values of x and y are).
I think it can be done via GraphQL, but I'm looking for a solution using the SDK. Can anyone help?

You can download historical rates from Trading Strategy websites as a Parquet file.

Two options

You can download historical rates from Trading Strategy websites as a Parquet file (preprocessed).

You can ask from an archive node using JSON-RPC, and set a block_number to a past block for your eth_call RPC method, which calls the Uniswap smart contract to get token0/token1 ratio.


You will find some historical Uniswap v3 price tutorial here.

Thanks. Do you know of any way this could be done through ethers.js or web3.js instead of the the eth_defi python library?

Yes it can be done. It is just matter of translating the code from one programming language/framework to another. Ethereum and its JSON-RPC APIs are the same for all programming languages.

with uniswap SDK you can only get the current swap rate. You'd need to combine this with GraphQL API to get historical data.
Hope this helps!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
